# Multiple ranking for large result set

Tags: mysql

I have a large Mysql table (approx 2 million rows). I want to run searches on it that will match possibly upto 25k rows (returned results will be limited [eg 25 per page]). What I wanted to do was to rank these results on cetain criteria and use that to order them.

The solution I have so far is to create a script go through the table and assign a score to each row based on my criteria. Each result would be given points depending on how it compared with my ideal result. I could then order by that score when executing a select, instead of caluculating on the fly.

I was then thinking that I wanted other users of the system to be able to setup their own custom scoring criteria. My first thought was to ceate a separate table that would contain the first tables row id, a users id and rank. But I was thinking that this table could get very large (2 million rows foreach user). So I am thinking of alternatives so far options I have are:

1) Use separate ranking table

2) Use user specific ranking tables

3) calculate on the fly

Anyone have any experience with a similar problem? The results will be searched in real time by users so my primary concern would be to make this part of the process as fast as possible.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I prefer seperate table, as you can generate a temporary new table while re-calculating, and rename the temp table to the real table.
This also may help you to bypass locking problems later...

Comment: Thanks, is that 1 separate table for all users/ranks?